# Determine what application/location the clipboard is pasting to?

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

I have a C# application that needs to determine where the clipboard is pasting to before it does so in order to disallow the paste to applications that are not allowed/supported. This will be a security application extension that companies will be able to enable when employees are attempting to copy from and paste outside of confidential, internal documents.

Is this possible? I've done a thorough search and looked through the following link, but didn't find anything that would be useful.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468802(v=vs.85).aspx

edit: I can easily determine if the application being copied from is one of ours, so this will only be enabled in that case. Copy/paste functionality through the rest of the system will work as it always does.

Comment: @user310291 Thanks bud, I think this is a reasonable request for a security application.

Comment: Are the destination apps your own? If so, you could use an encryption scheme that renders the data useless to anything but your own apps. During the paste to your app, the data is decrypted through your own proprietary algorithm.

Comment: @JamieMeyer The destination application would be, using one example, our Word VSTO Add-in, but your description is basically exactly what I'm looking for. After some more research, it looks like I need to create a custom, encrypted DataFormat with delayed rendering for the receiving application?

Comment: I do not understand the need for the delay by the receiver, but apart from that, this is what I was suggesting.

Comment: Delayed rendering is needed due to the fact that I need to either allow the paste of the confidential data or block it (alternatively encrypt it). This isn't possible without delayed rendering if you intend to protect all of the clipboard contents.